# how to take values after a specific point and discard values before it, in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector, find

I have an array, let's say

```
A =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
     2     3     4
     3     4     5
     1     6     8
```

I took a point from 3rd column, let's say p=9.

Now I want a new array that gives me all values after 9 and discards values before 9.
For example:

```
ans =

     7     8     9
     2     3     4
     3     4     5
     1     6     8
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
>> p = 9;
>> startrow = find(A(:, 3) == p, 1); % first row where 3rd column entry is p
>> A1 = A(startrow:end, :)

A1 =

     7     8     9
     2     3     4
     3     4     5
     1     6     8
```

Edit:

With multiple entries of p in the last column, you can vary how [find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) is used. For example, if you want to start at the last p instead of the first, you could run

```
>> startrow = find(A(:, 3) == p, 1, 'last'); % last row where 3rd column entry is p
```

If you want the second from first, you'd need a little more work:

```
>> startrows = find(A(:, 3) == p, 2); % first two rows where 3rd column entry is p
>> startrow = startrows(end); % Just the second row where 3rd column entry is p
```

Also, you probably need error checking if there is the possibility that p never appears in the array, or doesn't appear at least two times (for the last example).

Comment: if the matrix is like this A=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9;2 3 9;3 4 9;1 6 8]  i-e third colum contains 9 three times and i want to select 5th row that has 9 in it which is 3 4 9.......how to select it?

Comment: You can just output find result to a vector `startrow=find(A(:,3)==p);`, then use any index you want: `A1=A(startrow(2):end,:);`

Comment: if i want to discard values after point i-e p=9 and want to retain values before this point....than what to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you know what column the point is from you can simply do

```
B = A(n:end,:)
```

where n is the column number.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to delete the rows directly from the original matrix:

```
A(1:startrow-1,:)=[];
```